# Cannot get combined envelope document with SBS signatures

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to query for the combined Envelope document (all envelopes and certificate as one PDF). For this I'd use the EnvelopeDocuments interface, specifically via get request. But that responds me with an Error I do not know how to interpret.

Usually I'd make a REST-request from Java, but to rule out most errors I'm using the docusign [API Explorer](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/?explorer=true):

After entering the parameters the API explorer gives the url `/restapi/v2.1/accounts/7f[...]/envelopes/A5AAACA-[...]/documents/combined`, but the request just returns a 400 with following data:

```
{
  "message" : "Bad Request",
  "response" : {
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": [123, 34, ...]
  }
}
```

---

When I use `certificate` or some document-id instead of `combined` the api responds with the certificate or the document, as expected.

What am I doing wrong? And How do I interpret the response-data being a byte-buffer? Usually  error responses should contain a code and a message, but not more?

---

*EDIT:*
Actually, making a custom rest-request instead of using the api explorer gave me more insight with a Proper error message:

```
{
  "errorCode": "COMBINED_PDF_DOWNLOAD_NOT_ALLOWED",
  "message": "Setting Enable Combined PDF Download for SBS envelopes is turned off"
}
```

So, apparently I can not download a combined PDF, as the envelope was signed with a Qualified Electronic Signature.

But can I turn on combined download somehow? I could not find anything in the settings.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked just fine. Can you try again? a different envelope? double check your data? I'm not sure what was wrong, but I can't reproduce your issue

Comment: I also tried a different envelope, same issue.

Comment: But Using the API returned a proper error message, see post edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, you can't download a "combined" documents and certificate of completion PDF when the documents include a standards-based signature (SBS).

SBS signatures are digital X.509 signatures. That type of signature, by itself, guarantees both the identity of the signer and the integrity of the signed document.

If DocuSign created a combined PDF that included the SBS-signed document, then that document's SBS signatures would no longer be valid: not good.

### Recommendation

1. Download the signed documents separately from the certificate of completion.
2. The signed documents' signatures can be verified using any standards-based signature verification software (eg [validator.docusign.com](https://validator.docusign.com/))
3. The certificate of completion provides additional information on the documents' signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Combined PDF Download is a feature that you need to enable with the DocuSign support, you need to submit a case on their portal at https://support.docusign.com and request to enable this feature.

Comment: I think you misunderstood; In general I can download combined documents. But here I used SBS, which prohibited it (and I did not know these features correlate)